# Bad alloc thrown while using vector for knapsack algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, bad-alloc

I'm currently trying data structures and algorithms through a combination of online resources. For one of them, I attempted to solve the famous knapsack problem via a greedy algorithm. 
I'm sorting the weights and values of the problem in decreasing order before the loop in order to improve performance. 
When I run the code, I get a bad_alloc. Does this mean I'm just not allocating the memory that I need to? I've been looking for a solution but nothing has really been helpful so far, as I'm not doing explicit access to memory with the "new" identifier.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool decreaseSort(int a, int b)
{
    return a > b;   //sort by decreasing value for better performance
}

double get_optimal_value(int capacity, vector<int> weights, vector<int> values) {

sort(weights.begin(),weights.end(), decreaseSort); //sort weights
sort(values.begin(),weights.end(), decreaseSort); //sort values

vector<int> ourKnapsack(values.size()); //set Knapsack to n elements

for (size_t i = 0; i < ourKnapsack.size(); i++)
  ourKnapsack.push_back(0); //fill with zeroes


double totalValue = 0.0;  //total worth
int ourInput = 0; //what we are putting in

for (size_t j = 0; j < ourKnapsack.size(); j++){
  double unitValue = values.at(j)/weights.at(j); //ratio of value to weight for specific item

  if (capacity == 0) 
      return totalValue; //end program, return value


  if (weights.at(j) < capacity){
      ourInput = weights.at(j); //if we have room, fill with the weight
  }
  else {
      ourInput = capacity; //fill the rest of the pack
  }


  totalValue = totalValue * (ourInput * unitValue); //update totalValue
  weights.at(j)-=ourInput;  //subtract weight by what we put in
  ourKnapsack.at(j)+=ourInput; //update knapsack element
  capacity-=ourInput; //shrink capacity

 }
 return totalValue;
}

 int main() {
 int n = 3;  //test case, 3 items, capacity of 50
 int capacity = 50;

 vector<int> values(n);
 values = {60,100,120};
 vector<int> weights(n);
 weights = {20,50,30};

 double optimal_value = get_optimal_value(capacity, weights, values);

 std::cout.precision(10);
 std::cout << optimal_value << std::endl; //should return optimal value
 return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: To create a vector of size `values.size()` initialized with zeroes you can use `vector<int> ourKnapsack(values.size(), 0);`. There's no need to use a `for`.

Comment: If you want to use a `for` then use `i < values.size()` instead of `i < ourKnapsack.size()` as condition because the latter grows with your pushbacks, and `ourKnabsack[i] = 0` instead of push_back inside the loop. Anyhow prefer not using a for but the appropriate vector constructor.

Comment: As I predicted, something stupid. Thank you very much. This is the first time I've systematically coded anything in C++ for a year and my programming experience is dilletantish and screams autodidact at best, so please forgive me. I'm now getting a float exception error, but I think I know where that is stemming from. Have to take a short 15-20 minute recess for now, but I'll see if I can fix it right after, and if not, I'll ask.

Comment: Don't be too down on yourself.  I've been earning a living at programming for 35 years.  I *still* make this sort of stupid mistake.  The only difference is that I can usually find them myself (use your debugger).

Comment: Just to clarify the etiquette here: if you have a different problem, please ask a separate question.

Comment: @Anonymous Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < ourKnapsack.size(); i++)
  ourKnapsack.push_back(0); //fill with zeroes
```

This will go into an infinite loop.